# How to enforce Azure AD login through externally hosted site?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, azure, active-directory

Been googling this for hours, and can't find a clear tutorial or anything..

I have an Azure account with active directories already enabled. I also have an InMotion hosting account that hosts numerous domains (each having their own respective cpanels).

How would I go about integrating Azure AD authentication on a domain that's being hosted by InMotion that only affects that domain and none of the others on that hosting account?

So in theory, you would visit the domain, get hit with the Windows login Auth. page, and if login is successful, you are directed to the home page and can view the content.

Is this do-able through the `.htaccess` file? Or would I have to alter the actual Apache files? If so, how do I only make it applicable to only one domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate the web app with Azure AD, we need to write the custom code to implement the logic to redirect the unauthenticated request to Azure AD and verify the token after users sign-in. ( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-code-samples) about the code samples to integrate with Azure AD)

And it is more easy if you deploy the web app on Azure. In this scenario, we can use the [authentication and authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service-web%2Ftoc.json) feature provide by Azure which we don't have to change code on the web application.

> How would I go about integrating Azure AD authentication on a domain that's being hosted by InMotion that only affects that domain and none of the others on that hosting account?

Based on my understanding, we integrate the Azure AD with web app and config the domain for the web site. Then we can visit the web app via the domain instead of ip address. In this scenario, only the web app you integrate with Azure AD will be redirect to the login page if users are accessing the page which require authentication when users doesn't login.